# What's the point of the Quantity field in CloudFront's create_invalidation call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

The CloudFront `create_invalidation` API lets you specify a `Quantity` which seems redundant. Is there a use case for setting a `Quantity` different from the length of `Items`?

```
response = client.create_invalidation(
  DistributionId = 'string',
  InvalidationBatch = {
    'Paths': {
      'Quantity': 2,
      'Items': [
        '/index.html',
        '/image.png',
      ]
    },
    'CallerReference': 'string'
  }
)
```

Comment: It's just a wild guess of mine, but I think it puts a limit on how many keys are invalidated when using wildcards like `images/*`. But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Paths.html) says that the quantity field is required, and integer, and "The number of invalidation paths specified for the objects that you want to invalidate."

One usecase for supplying a smaller number than the number of items might be: sending more data than necessary to the AWS API.

A usecase for supplying a larger number might be: trying to trigger an error condition in the AWS API.

I would suggest just using the API as documented.

Comment: The problem is that the documentation is not clear about how to use the `Quantity` field